# How to convert kotlin Result type from List<Result<T>> to Result<List<T>>

Tags: kotlin

I have `List<Result<String>>` and I would like to convert it to `Result<List<String>>`. I understand that `List<Result<String>>` could have both failure and successful results but I would like to terminate in the first failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a failure as soon there is one Result that is a failure you can do this :

```kotlin
fun <T> List<Result<T>>.toResult() = if (any { it.isFailure }) {
        Result.failure<List<Result<Any>>>(Throwable("A result has errors"))
    } else {
        Result.success(map { it.getOrNull() })
    }
```

With this code, you get a failure as soon as there is one value has a failure.

Or if you don't care handling the error yourself :

```kotlin
fun <T> List<Result<T>>.toResult() = runCatching {
    Result.success(map { it.getOrThrow() })
}
```

Comment: Note that you need to make a choice regarding which of potentially multiple errors to report in the final Result<List> or like in the code above report something generic

Answer (score 0):

In most libraries this function is known as `sequence`.
Kotlin's Arrow library implements it for its implementation of the type `Either`, which is a generalization of `Result`: https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-core/arrow.core/sequence.html

With Arrow's Either you would write:

```
val xs: List<Result<String>> = ...
val ys: Result<List<String>> = xs.sequence()
```

The Kotlin stdlib does not seem to have it. You could define it as an extension method using `getOrThrow`, catching any thrown `Throwable` and wrapping in a `Result`again:

```kotlin
fun <T> List<Result<T>>.sequence(): Result<List<T>> = try {
    Result.success(this.map { it.getOrThrow() })
  }
  catch (e:Throwable) { Result.failure(e) }
```

Comment: You can further simplify things by calling `runCatching { map { it.getOrThrow() } }` from the stdlib.

Comment: Indeed you can!